# SharePoint HTML conversion

Tags: xml

I all new to this so I may be making a rookie error.

I am trying to use the SharePoint design manager to convert a HTML site and I am just using a HTML template from adobe for now.

When I try and do this I get the following error. (See the attached picture)

[image]

Hope someone can help me understand what is going on here.

Comment: By the looks of the error - you should type ’Doctype’ in uppercase.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Check your html code is correct or not? sometime it happens when some tags are missing or not closed properly. better you check your HTML code from here https://validator.w3.org/ then use that code to generate master page then see the result.